# How do Calvinists interpret "Your word is a lamp to my feet And a light to my path" and "He shall direct your paths"?

Tags: exegesis, reformed-theology, arminianism

Do Calvinists interpret the following verses to support predestination? 
-   “Your word is a lamp to my feet And a light to my path” (Psa 119:105)
-   “In all your ways acknowledge Him, And He shall direct your paths” (Pro 3:6)

If so, is their view only that God predestined our salvation or also that he predestined everything (e.g., which colleges we would attend, which spouses we would marry, which jobs we would take, etc.)?

Is it significantly different to how Arminians interpret the above verses?

Comment: Typically, one or the other view per question is how the community here wants questions organized. I've changed the wording a little bit to reflect this.

Comment: Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions.

Comment: I think it would be better to make a separate question asking what Arminians believe.

Comment: I think that asking about those verses is really a distraction from your main question. You want to know what their doctrine of predestination is, right? Giving an interpretation of those verses won't lead to an answer. It would be better to cut them and ask directly what they believe about predestination.

Comment: Of course its significantly different from how Arminians interpret the verses. Calvinists make everything about predestination. If they read "Repent!" they say "Aha, this proves predestination!" Whereas an Arminian (in the loose sense of a non-Calvinist, since classical Arminians really are just another brand of Calvinism) will say: "He commands them to repent, which shows we have freewill, and therefore predestination is bunk."

Answer (score 3):

Reformed Theology (Calvinism) does teach that God is absolutely in control over everything, which means predetermining every tiny detail.

John Piper was asked the question ['Has God Predetermined Every Tiny Detail In the Universe, Including Sin?' (video and transcript)](http://www.desiringgod.org/interviews/has-god-predetermined-every-tiny-detail-in-the-universe-including-sin), and he begun his answer with this:

> Yes.
>
> There's a great quote from Spurgeon about dust motes. You may not even know what a dust mote is, but when I get up in the morning in my room, there's a window to the side of the bed, and a beam of light will be shining through it at certain times of the year when I get it.
>
> Now when I look through the dark I see nothing. But when I look through the beam I see the dust in the room. It's flying around, and I say, "I'm breathing that stuff!?" Yes, you are. And Spurgeon says that every one of those particles is keeping its position and moving through the air by God's appointment.
>
> Now the reason I believe that is because the Bible says, "The dice are thrown in the lap, and every decision is from the Lord" (Proverbs 16:33). Proverbs 16 has a bunch of these verses in it.
>
> Why would he choose "the die is cast into the lap"? It's because he's trying to think of the most random thing he could think of. And he says that. So randomness is not random to God.
>
> God is not the least taxed by keeping every sub-nuclear particle in its place. I used to say electrons, but now there's something smaller than electrons. Everything in the middle of the molecule moving, and the electrons—he's got them all in orbit, just like he has the planets in orbit.